# bsDatepicker set minDate for endDate

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

i am trying to set endDate inputs minDate to be startDates + 1 day value.
what am i doing wrong?

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-bootstrap-starter-bkdi1s?file=src/app/app.component.html)

**.ts**

```
this.minendDate.setDate(this.minendDate.getDate() + 1);
this.maxendDate.setDate(this.maxendDate.getDate() + 365);
this.form.get('startDate').valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
  console.log(value);
  this.minendDate.setDate(value + 1);
});
```

**.html**

```
      <input formControlName="startDate"
        [minDate]="minstartDate"
        [maxDate]="maxstartDate"
        bsDatepicker
        #dp="bsDatepicker"
        autocomplete="off"
        [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true }"  />

      <input
        formControlName="endDate"
        [minDate]="minendDate"
        [maxDate]="maxendDate"
        bsDatepicker
        #dp="bsDatepicker"
        autocomplete="off"
        [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true }" />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can set using `bsValueChange`. try below way i hope it work for you.

```
   this.minendDate.setDate(this.minendDate.getDate() + 1);
   this.maxendDate.setDate(this.maxendDate.getDate() + 365);

   changeStartDate(value){
        var nextDay = new Date(value);
        nextDay.setDate(nextDay.getDate() + 1);
        this.minendDate = nextDay;
   }
```

html

```
<input formControlName="startDate"
    [minDate]="minstartDate"
    [maxDate]="maxstartDate"
    bsDatepicker
    #dp="bsDatepicker"
    autocomplete="off"
    [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true }"
    (bsValueChange)= "changeStartDate($event)"
     />

  <input
    formControlName="endDate"
    [minDate]="minendDate"
    [maxDate]="maxendDate"
    bsDatepicker
    #dp="bsDatepicker"
    autocomplete="off"
    [bsConfig]="{ adaptivePosition: true }" />
```

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer it works for current month but not for the other months ! i edited my stackblitz

Comment: okay i have updated my ans as per your requirement check it once and try it now it working for all month.